# HTML video player sound cuts out after through skimming video

Tags: javascript, html, h.264, acc

I'm currently having issues with a dynamically loaded html video player on my site, where I set the source of a HTML video player using JS by clicking on a button.

The problem is, once the video is playing it runs fine, but as soon as I skim the video or jump ahead, doesn't matter how far, the sound is lost and doesn't sync back up with the video, even though I'm on a fast connection and the video itself continues to play without any hiccups or buffering.

The video is a MP4 encoded in H.264 and ACC 160bit.

What could this be due to?

EDIT: *this problem only seems to occur on iOS devices, and on any browser*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue was playback on iOS devices using the Safari browser (*other browsers not currently tested*), and it was due to the encoding used on the videos, was not optimal for those circumstances.

Solution: encode all videos in H.264 and AAC for audio, there are some very useful presets  that can help you do this in *[HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/)*.